# Python Re: tested regex patterns returning no matches

Tags: python, regex

Using the python below I am trying to find specific headings with a markdown file

```
import re

source_file = open('readme.md')

#Defines variables containing the headings as Regex searches

product_name = re.compile('(?mi)^#+[^\S\n]product.*name')
product_version = re.compile('(?mi)^#+[^\S\n]product.*version')
product_description = re.compile('(?mi)^#+[^\S\n]product.*description')

#Adds the required headings to a list
headings = [product_name, product_version, product_description]

#Opens the readme, searches for the specified headings, then uses print_section to print the content under the headings
with open('readme.md') as file:
    for x in headings:
        content = x.search(file.read()).group(0)
        print(content)
```

The readme.md file contains the following placeholder text

```
# Product Name
Test Product
## Product Version
0.01
## Product Description
A short overview of what this product is; what it does; and what its intended use case is
# Specifications
## Networking
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
## Data Usage
This is line one of the sample
This is line two of the sample
```

The response I get from running this file is:

```
# Product Name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 16, in <module>
    content = x.search(file.read()).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

So I think there is an issue with the 2nd and 3rd Regex patterns. However in regex testers they [appear to match properly](https://regex101.com/r/DyTENp/5). I can't really spot any differences between these patterns and the first which is successful, I've even tried swapping the ordering of the content in the markdown file, and still only product_name matches.

Comment: You really should be using raw strings (`r'...'` or `r"..."`) for the regular expressions.  I don't think it's actually causing a problem in this case, but regular string literals may interpret backslashes in a different way than the regex engine does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file only once, and search it:

```
with open('readme.md') as file:
    f = file.read()
    for x in headings:
        content = x.search(f).group(0)
        print(content)
```

As soon as Python `read()` reaches the end of the file (basically after your first iteration), it will keep returning an empty string. And you keep getting NoneType error because you search an empty string.